# LOOKUP function if cells MATCH

Tags: excel, if-statement, lookup-tables

I am looking for help with the following problem:

`DATA` spreadsheet: Raw data - contains balance sheet, income information, etc (several columns with dates on top)

`Peer Comp` spreadsheet: output table

So, I'm looking to search a cell in `DATA` spreadsheet for a value that matches another cell in `Peer Comp` spreadsheet, and return the gross revenues value from the `DATA` spreadsheet into the Peer Comp spreadsheet under the column that matched.

Here is my current formula. I can't find my mistake...

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH('Peer Comp'!B3,DATA!A:O,0)),HLOOKUP(B3,DATA!B3:M426,198,FALSE), 0)
```

Essentially, I just need to return a value from the `Data` spreadsheet to the `Pear Comp` spreadsheet from the column that matched the date in the `Peer Comp` table.

Comment: Maybe INDEX/MATCH would work better?  `=INDEX(DATA!B3:M426,198,MATCH('Peer Comp'!B3,DATA!B3:M3,0))`

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `IF(ISNA(), [then 0], [else lookup])`?

Comment: Scott Craner's solution worked! Thanks a million!

Comment: I ran into a problem and looking for suggestions from Excel Gurus. Using the above example, I am needing the formula to return value from a row number labeled "Net Sales" (instead of a specific row number). What modifications would I need to make to my formula to get the right output?    Here is the formula I'm using:   =INDEX(DATA!B3:M426,198,MATCH('Peer Comp'!B3,DATA!B3:M3,0))         In other words, I need to substitute "198" with a lookup for "Net Sales" exact match. Please Help!